# Are lightlike curves in the De Sitter space straight lines?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, semi-riemannian-geometry

I think that every lightlike curve in $\mathbb{S}_1^2 \subseteq \mathbb{L}^3$ must be a line. But I'm having trouble concluding it.

Let $\alpha\colon I \subseteq \Bbb R \to \Bbb S^2_1 \subseteq \Bbb L^3$ be a lightlike curve. Then: $$\langle \alpha, \alpha \rangle = 1, \quad \langle \alpha', \alpha' \rangle = 0.$$From here, we obtain: $$\langle \alpha, \alpha' \rangle = 0, \quad \langle \alpha', \alpha '' \rangle = 0.$$So far all of this is trivial. Differentiating $\langle \alpha, \alpha'\rangle = 0$ we get: $$0 = \langle \alpha',\alpha'\rangle + \langle \alpha, \alpha''\rangle \implies \langle \alpha, \alpha''\rangle = 0.$$

Intuition says that $\alpha''$ is in the plane spanned by $\alpha$ and $\alpha'$ (since $\alpha''$ would point to the origin), so the above calculation would give that $\langle \alpha'',\alpha''\rangle = 0$, but I'm not sure of this. And even if this is true, it doesn't mean that $\alpha'' = 0$.

Can someone help me or give a counter-example? This is a self-posed question, made after noticing that every line contained in $\mathbb{S}^2_1$ must be lightlike. I just wondered about the reciprocal.

---

The Lorentz product is given by $\langle {\bf x},{\bf y}\rangle = x_1y_1+x_2y_2-z_1z_2$, and $\mathbb{S}^2_1$ is the set of all vectors $\bf v$ such that $\langle {\bf v},{\bf v}\rangle = 1$, in case I didn't make it clear before. Use whatever signature for $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ you want, though, it probably won't appear in the computations. The result seems to be true for $\Bbb L^n$ in general, if that's really the case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to fix the ideas, let the Lorentzian metric on the Minkowski space $\mathbb{L}^3$ have signature $-++$. The Lorentz group $O(1,2)$ of $\mathbb{L}^3$, on the one hand, acts transitively on the subset $\mathbb{S}^2_1 \subset \mathbb{L}^3$ and, on the other hand, is a subgroup of the linear group $\mathrm{Gl}(3, \mathbb{R})$.

The first fact implies that null-curves of $\mathbb{S}^2_1$ are sent to null-curves by the action of $O(1,2)$. Furthermore, since $\mathbb{S}^2_1$ is a 2-dimensional manifold, there are at any point only two null-directions, so that there are (up to parametrization) only two null-curves going through any fix point. This observation allows one to show that $O(1,2)$ acts transitively on the set of null-curves of $\mathbb{S}^2_1$.

The second fact implies that affine lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are sent to affine lines under the action of $O(1,2)$.

Combining these two consequences, in order to conclude that any null-curve is a straight line, we only have to show that a null straight line passes through the point $p(t,x,y) = (0,0,1)$. At $T_p\mathbb{S}^2_1$, the vector $v = \partial_t + \partial_x = (1,1,0)$ is null, so we would like to show that the line $\gamma(t) = p + tv$ (i) belongs to $\mathbb{S}^2_1$ and (ii) is everywhere lightlike. Fix any $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

(i) $\langle \gamma(t), \gamma(t) \rangle  = \langle p, p \rangle + 2 t \langle p, v \rangle = \langle p, p \rangle = 1 \, .$

(ii) It is clear that $v = \dot{\gamma}(t) \in T_{\gamma(t)} \mathbb{L}^3$ is null. According to (i), $\dot{\gamma}(t) \in T_{\gamma(t)} \mathbb{S}^2_1$, so it also has to be null inside this subplane.

---

This argument uses in an essential way the homogeneity of the de Sitter space. However, in order to deduce that the space of null-curves is also an $O(1,2)$-homogeneous space, it uses the fact that $\mathbb{S}^2_1$ is 2-dimensional. Indeed, in dimension three or more, the lightcone without the origin is a dimension two, etc. manifold with two connected components (in dimension two, it is a 1-dimensional manifold with four components), so that there is a lot of room for non-straight null-curve.

In order to get a similar result for the various $\mathbb{S}^n_1$, one would need to put some further constraints on the null-curves, like being geodesics. Indeed, $O(1,n)$ also acts transitively on $\mathbb{S}^n_1$ ; the stabilizer of the point $p(t, x_1, \dots, x_n) = (0, 0, \dots, 0,1)$ is easily seen to be isomorphic to $O(1,n-1)$. Now, one shows that the stabilizer acts transitively on the lightcone inside $T_p \mathbb{S}^n_1$ i.e. $O(1,n-1)$ acts transitively on the lightcone inside $\mathbb{L}^{n-1}$. Hence, $O(1,n)$ acts transitively on the set of null-vectors in $T\mathbb{S}^n_1$. Moreover, since $O(1,n)$ acts through isometries, it sends (null-)geodesic to (null-)geodesic. Since (null-)geodesic going through some given point are in bijection with the set of (null-)vectors at that point, we deduce that $O(1,n)$ acts transitively on the set of (null-)geodesics. Since, as argued above, there exists a straight null-curve and as it is certainly a geodesic*, we deduce that all null-geodesics of $\mathbb{S}^n_1$ are straight lines.

$^*$ Geodesics are curves of vanishing geodesic curvature, which is a measure of the amount of the ambient curvature that is 'tangent' to the hypersurface. A straight line having no ambient curvature, it doesn't have geodesic curvature either.

Comment: Wow, great answer. Very well explained, thanks a lot.